# Using a 3-phase Transformer After a Variable Frequency Drive for Voltage Reduction

Tags: motor, transformer, induction-motor, vfd

In the plating industry generally 42V - 3P motors are used to rotate the barrels that hold the products to be plated. This is because the contacts of the barrel cannot be isolated (because barrels are moving from bath to bath) so a reduced voltage is used for safety. Normally, we use a 380V to 42V transformer to drive the barrels at 50Hz and select the gearbox according to the desired rotating speed of the barrel.

But in this case our customer asked about variable rotation speed of the barrels. There are two options for achieving this I can think of.

1. **Use a VFD at the input of the transformer.** This will probably work but I'm guessing there will be losses at the transformer since the output of the VFD is essentially chopped DC. Also, the harmonics may cause mechanical stress on the windings.
2. **Use a VFD at the output of the transformer.** This would be a valid option, but I couldn't find any VFD that works with 42V input.

Are my concerns valid? Are there any other concerns for these approaches? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Also, any references would be good to know.

Comment: Will the transformer work at lower frequencies? I don't think so.

Comment: @mkeith This is a good point. I think even if it works the efficiency would be very bad probably.

Comment: I'd say, use a VFD and motor at 480v. Then use a galvanically-isolated [mechanical coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling) between the motor and gearbox/barrel. The motor chassis will be Earth grounded, so isolation only needs to be ~50v with respect to barrel.  And use shielded power wiring (or metal conduit) to the motor to prevent any EMI from getting into the plating circuitry.

Comment: Transformer losses can be modelled to decide whether they are acceptable ... they may be, down to say half speed, but not much lower. (and you haven't specified a speed range). You mainly need to know the primary inductance : or have transformers wound with an unusually high primary inductance. And custom winding isn't all that expensive.

Comment: Maybe you can find a 48V servomotor or consider using a brushed 48VDC motor with simple controller.

Comment: Did you manage to find any VFDs operating at 42V, and did you end up connecting one at the output of the transformer?

Comment: @George I ended up convincing the customer that it is not worth it :) But during my research I found someone else doing the same thing by using VFD at the input of the transformer. They said they could only go about 20% of the maximum speed. But I imagine there were too many losses.

Comment: @obareey Noted, we'd like to use <50V for safety also, and 3-phase AC would also allow control of the direction of rotation. We might test a transformer/VFD setup at some point, but as you said it involved high losses and not cost efficient either. Did you end up using a <50V BLDC motor?

Comment: @George No, we ordered 42V 3-phase AC motors from the manufacturer with custom windings. It costs a little bit higher but not very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transformer will work with variable frequency, but there are some design challenges involved. VFDs generally do not maintain constant V/Hz down to the minimum operating frequency. V/Hz is increased because the voltage drop in the motor winding resistance becomes more significant at lower operating voltages. Rather than using a 380:24 volt transformer with a 380 V VFD, you should use 480:48 V transformer with a 240 V VFD. The transformer should also be sized to provide more secondary current than the motor requires to compensate for additional heating due to the waveform. The VFD rating will need to be increased to supply the transformer losses and magnetizing current.

Early in the history of VFDs, this was done to control 480 V motors with 240 V VFDs prior to the availability of semiconductors suitable to build 480 V VFDs.