# Using a 575 V to 220 V step-down transformer to power a 3 hp, 575 V motor with a 220 V VFD

Tags: transformer, motor, high-current, legal

I have a uniquely designed motor for a milling machine (expensive to replace and to purchase at a lower voltage).

What I want to do is purchase a 575 V primary, 220 V secondary 3p used transformer, plug the motor in the primary and a cheap VFD into the secondary.

The goal is to reverse the current flow to get that 575 V by plugging the 220 V sources into the secondary.

I am aware that the transformer is not made to work that way and will lose some power thanks to the winding, and also generate more heat; I've read 5-10% online, but I don't know if that number is reliable or not. As for the heat, I could set up a fan to cool the transformer, if it's not too much.

What I want to know is if I'm going to burn my house down, damage my motor, waste my money, or injure myself with such a setup. I'd also like to know if it's illegal to do something like this, if someone happens to know about that (I live in Canada).

The motor's max. power is 3 hp (very unlikely to be reached), the transformer's power is 3.11 hp (2850 VA @ 0.814 power factor). The VFD spec is "It's going to be enough for this application", since I haven’t made a choice for this one yet.

I also know that the top current into the motor is higher than the one into the transformer. The only time this current is reached (or is even near maximum) is when the machine stalls (and you slap the emergency power-off when that happens).

[image: Transformer label]

[image: Motor label]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485805/using-a-3-phase-transformer-after-a-variable-frequency-drive-for-voltage-reducti

Comment: No, I am more worried about the risk of using a transistor step down as a step up than using a VFD for getting 3P current. Still, thank for your input.

Comment: What would be the problem in using a step-down transformer as a step-up transformer?

Comment: Going against the the polarity of the core could cause an excessive amount of heat and an higher inrush current. I'd like to know by how much and if it would be dangerous.

Comment: The core does not have a polarity to consider here. I forget the reason to place primary or secondary closer to the core. The transformer *does* have a voltage&frequency rating: at less than 50 Hz, driving the 220 V secondary should overexcite/saturate the core. A VFD *may* compensate for that, keeping voltage/frequency. At higher frequencies, core losses may increase. It *may* be possible to use the transformer as an autotransformer - do you need isolation?